# How to stretch projection by a percentage (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a map that uses the equirectangular projection (EPSG:3786). This makes the map look compressed towards the equator and I want to stretch it by 120% vertically whilst still retaining the correct points. The nearest thing I can find is GRASS' v.transform, but that simply stretches the dataset, causing it to have incorrect real world coordinates.
[image]

Comment: You would be better off just picking a different projection

Comment: Ian Turton, I would but the problem is I want it to be compatible with a Lua module that only supports this projection, so stretching it vertically is the only way to correct the proportions and retain compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Ian Turton, at least from a GIS point of view, it would be better to choose another projection. If you still want to simply stretch, you can use the almost unlimited power of QGIS expressions with [Geoemtry Generator](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/basic_map/symbology.html#hard-fa-geometry-generator-symbology) or [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) (see [here for details](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)).

The expression takes the vertices of each polygon and shifts it for a certain, freely definable amount away from a point inside the polygon, in this way stretching the polygon vertically. The amount the polygon is stretched can be changed on line 3 (here: `0.2`). This is the expression to use:

```
with_variable (
    'stretch',
    0.2,
    make_polygon( 
        make_line( 
            array_foreach (
                generate_series (1,  num_points( $geometry)),
                make_point (
                    x (point_n( $geometry,@element)),
                    y (point_n ($geometry,@element)) - 
                    @stretch * (y (point_on_surface ($geometry)) - y (point_n ($geometry,@element)))
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

**Option**

You could also replace `point_on_surface` (line 11) by `centroid` if the polygons you want to stretch do not shift evenly (depending on the shape of the polygons).

*Screenshot: initial polygons (red) and streched version (blue), using Geometry generator with the expression above:*
[image]